# How to return empty queryset from serializer.data Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

view.py

```
class User_ListView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [DjangoCustomModelPermissions]
    queryset = User.objects.none()

    def get(self, request):
        param1 = request.query_params.get('param1',None) 
        param2 = request.query_params.get('param2',None)

        try:
            db_data = User.objects.get(param1 = param1, param2=param2)
            serializer = User_Serializer(db_data)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        except Closing_Stock_List_Trans.DoesNotExist:
            db_data = User.objects.none()
            serializer = User_Serializer(db_data)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

serializer.py

```
class User_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

I want the serializer to return an empty response when no User DoesNotExist in the User Model, however I get the following error. How can i achieve this?

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `param1` on serializer `User_Serializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.
Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'param1'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to serialize a queryset, so you need to add `many=True` to the serialization.

```
....
except Closing_Stock_List_Trans.DoesNotExist:
    db_data = User.objects.none()
    serializer = User_Serializer(db_data, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: This works, thanks. Just a follow up question. Currently I return status 200 if object is found and if it isnt i return and Empty list as Response. If i have any other error what status should i return, should it be 500?